# How to optimize LINQ expressions?

Tags: optimization, linq-expressions

On a project built with .NET 3.5, I am using LINQ expressions to dynamically generate code at runtime. The LINQ expressions are compiled using the Compile method and stored for later use as predicates with LINQ to objects.

The expressions are sometimes quite complicated and difficult to debug.

Below is an example of an expression viewed through the debugger visualizer in Visual Studio.

> {request
>   => (Invoke(workEnvelopeHead
>   => (workEnvelopeHead.Method = value(Wombl.Scenarios.CannedResponses+<>c_*DisplayClass58).pipeline),
>   request.WorkEnvelope.Head)
>   And Invoke(body =>
>   Invoke(value(Wombl.Scenarios.CannedResponses+<>c*_DisplayClass78).isMatch,
>   body.SingleOrDefault()),Convert(request.WorkEnvelope.Body.Any)))}

I would like to be able to optimize expressions like the above so that the `value(Wombl.Scenarios.CannedResponses+<>c__DisplayClass58).pipeline` expression is replaced with a constant that is the variable's value.

In this particular case, `value(Wombl.Scenarios.CannedResponses+<>c__DisplayClass58).pipeline` is a reference in the lambda to a variable in the parent scope. Something like:

```
var pipeline = "[My variable's value here]";
// My lambda expression here, which references pipeline
// Func<RequestType, bool> predicate = request => ........ workEnvelopeHead.Method == pipeline ..........
```

The original expression, optimized ought to look like:

> {request => (Invoke(workEnvelopeHead =>
>   (workEnvelopeHead.Method = "[My variable's value here]",
>   request.WorkEnvelope.Head) And Invoke(body => > Invoke(value(Wombl.Scenarios.CannedResponses+<>c__DisplayClass78).isMatch,
>   body.SingleOrDefault()),Convert(request.WorkEnvelope.Body.Any)))}

**How can I make such optimizations at runtime to the LINQ expression, before compiling?**

Comment: You're talking about "optimizing" but the only problem you've given is *debugging*. It's possible that some things which may make it easier to debug will hurt performance, or vice versa. Could you clarify which goal is important to you?

Comment: By optimizing, I mean rewriting the expression tree in a simpler form which _should_ improve performance and make the expression tree easier to read. So while both improved runtime performance and readability are goals, readability of the expression is of more importance. The expression is written to a log during runtime to aid in debugging.

Comment: I'm considering writing an ExpressionVisitor to rewrite the expression tree replacing the variable references with a constant that has the value of the variable. However, I'm hoping that someone else has tried to do something similar and that maybe the solution already exists.

Comment: Yes, a visitor is probably what you need. Expression trees are nice in many ways, but they're a pain to manipulate like this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went ahead and wrote an expression visitor that replaces the variable references with the actual value. It wasn't so hard to do after all.

Usage:

```
var simplifiedExpression = ExpressionOptimizer.Simplify(complexExpression);
```

The class:

It inherits from ExpressionVisitor which came from the code samples on [this page](http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx) because in .NET 3.0 it is internal. In .NET 4.0 the class is public but might require some changes to this class.

```
public sealed class ExpressionOptimizer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ExpressionOptimizer()
    {
    }

    #region Methods

    public static Expression<TDelegate> Simplify<TDelegate>(Expression<TDelegate> expression)
    {
        return expression == null
                   ? null
                   : (Expression<TDelegate>) new ExpressionOptimizer().Visit(expression);
    }

    private static bool IsPrimitive(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsPrimitive
               || type.IsEnum
               || type == typeof (string)
               || type == typeof (DateTime)
               || type == typeof (TimeSpan)
               || type == typeof (DateTimeOffset)
               || type == typeof (Decimal)
               || typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        var constantExpression = memberExpression.Expression as ConstantExpression;

        if (constantExpression == null || !IsPrimitive(memberExpression.Type))
            return base.VisitMemberAccess(memberExpression);

        // Replace the MemberExpression with a ConstantExpression
        var constantValue = constantExpression.Value;
        var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        var value = propertyInfo == null
                        ? ((FieldInfo) memberExpression.Member).GetValue(constantValue)
                        : propertyInfo.GetValue(constantValue, null);

        return Expression.Constant(value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```